# difference in notation of integral operator

Tags: neural-network, convolution, definition, integral-operator

I'm reading [paper 1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.08895.pdf) and on page 4 they define the integral operator $\mathcal{K}$ as

$$
(\mathcal{K}(a;\phi)v_t)(x) :=  \int_D \kappa(x,y,a(x),a(y);\phi)v_t(y)dy
$$

Now in an [another paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.03697.pdf) from the same group, they define the integral operator $\mathcal{K}$ on page 8 as

$$
(\mathcal{K}v_l)(x) := \int_D \kappa(x,y)v_l(y)dv_l(y)
$$

I'm pretty sure these definitions are essentially the same, but what confuses me is that the integration in the first definition is with respect to $dy$ and in the integration in the second is with respect to $dv_l(y)$. Is this difference just technical? i.e. are these different ways of saying the same thing?

In the first case the integration is with respect to $y$ so its a simple integration. In the second case, the integration seems to be with respect to functions $dv_l(y)$. Is this correct?

Edit:

I think @davidhigh is correct about it being a typo. Equation 9 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.03794.pdf) seems to be the correct definition, even though I don't know enough measure theory to be able to conclude conclusively.

$$
(\mathcal{K}v_l)(x) = \int_D \kappa^{(l)}(x,y)v_l(y)d\nu(y)
$$

Comment: The second formulation seems strange to me, I would assume a copy-and-paste error, remember, it's only a preprint. The second further resembles an integral over a measure $dv_l$, but then it's strange that the measure is again under the integral. So summarizing, I'd use the first definition (in terms of a measure-theoretic density).

Comment: @davidhigh updated my post above.

Comment: Even if they use measure-theoretic notation, in the numerical implementation it will always boil down to an integral as in the first equation. So no need to worry.